# Set thresholds in PySpark multinomial logistic regression

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, logistic-regression, apache-spark-ml

I would like to perform a multinomial logistic regression but I can't set `threshold` and `thresholds` parameters correctly. Consider the following DF:

```python
from pyspark.ml.linalg import DenseVector

test_train_df = (
sqlc
.createDataFrame([(0, DenseVector([-1.0, 1.2, 0.7])),
                  (0, DenseVector([3.1, -2.0, -2.9])),
                  (1, DenseVector([1.0, 0.8, 0.3])),
                  (1, DenseVector([4.2, 1.4, -1.7])),
                  (0, DenseVector([-1.9, 2.5, -2.3])),
                  (2, DenseVector([2.6, -0.2, 0.2])),
                  (1, DenseVector([0.3, -3.4, 1.8])),
                  (2, DenseVector([-1.0, -3.5, 4.7]))],
                 ['label', 'features'])
)
```

My label has 3 classes, so I have to set `thresholds` (plural, which default is `None`) rather than `threshold` (singular, which default is `0.5`). Then I write:

```python
from pyspark.ml import classification as cl

test_logit_abst = (
    cl.LogisticRegression()
    .setFamily('multinomial')
    .setThresholds([.5, .5, .5])
)
```

Then I would like to fit the model on my DF:

```python
test_logit = test_logit_abst.fit(test_train_df)
```

but when executing this last command I get an error:

```python
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    320             else:

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o3769.fit.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Logistic Regression found inconsistent values for threshold and thresholds.  Param threshold is set (0.5), indicating binary classification, but Param thresholds is set with length 3. Clear one Param value to fix this problem.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

IllegalArgumentException                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-211-8f3443f41b6b> in <module>()
----> 1 test_logit = test_logit_abst.fit(test_train_df)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/ml/base.py in fit(self, dataset, params)
     62                 return self.copy(params)._fit(dataset)
     63             else:
---> 64                 return self._fit(dataset)
     65         else:
     66             raise ValueError("Params must be either a param map or a list/tuple of param maps, "

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py in _fit(self, dataset)
263
    264     def _fit(self, dataset):
--> 265         java_model = self._fit_java(dataset)
    266         return self._create_model(java_model)
267

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py in _fit_java(self, dataset)
    260         """
    261         self._transfer_params_to_java()
--> 262         return self._java_obj.fit(dataset._jdf)
263
    264     def _fit(self, dataset):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1131         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1132         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
1134
   1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     77                 raise QueryExecutionException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
     78             if s.startswith('java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: '):
---> 79                 raise IllegalArgumentException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
     80             raise
     81     return deco

IllegalArgumentException: 'requirement failed: Logistic Regression found inconsistent values for threshold and thresholds.  Param threshold is set (0.5), indicating binary classification, but Param thresholds is set with length 3. Clear one Param value to fix this problem.'
```

The error says `threshold` is set. This looks strange, as the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression.setThresholds) says that setting `thresholds` (plural) clears `threshold` (singular), so that the value `0.5` should be deleted.
So, how to clear `threshold` since no `clearThreshold()` exists?

In order to achieve this I tried to clear `threshold` this way:

```python
logit_abst = (
    cl.LogisticRegression()
    .setFamily('multinomial')
    .setThresholds([.5, .5, .5])
    .setThreshold(None)
)
```

This time the fit command works, I even obtain the model intercept and coefficients:

```python
test_logit.interceptVector
DenseVector([65.6445, 31.6369, -97.2814])

test_logit.coefficientMatrix
DenseMatrix(3, 3, [-76.4534, -19.4797, -79.4949, 12.3659, 4.642, 4.1057, 64.0876, 14.8377, 75.3892], 1)
```

But if I try to get `thresholds` (plural) from `test_logit_abst` I get an error:

```python
test_logit_abst.getThresholds()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-214-fc1c8617ce80> in <module>()
----> 1 test_logit_abst.getThresholds()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/ml/classification.py in getThresholds(self)
    363         if not self.isSet(self.thresholds) and self.isSet(self.threshold):
    364             t = self.getOrDefault(self.threshold)
--> 365             return [1.0-t, t]
    366         else:
    367             return self.getOrDefault(self.thresholds)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'NoneType'
```

What does this mean?

---

As a further detail, curiously (and incomprehensibly to me) inverting the order of the parameters settings produces the first error I posted above:

```python
logit_abst = (
    cl.LogisticRegression()
    .setFamily('multinomial')
    .setThreshold(None)
    .setThresholds([.5, .5, .5])
)
```

Why does changing the order of the "set" instructions change the output as well?

Comment: Cannot reproduce neither of your errors in Spark 2.1.1 or 2.2.0. Do you get them when just declaring the model, as shown in your post, or you imply that you get them when trying to actually *fit* the model with data? If it is the second, please edit your post to clarify this and show the actual commands that produce the error(s)

Comment: All the errors I get come after the code I wrote: in the first two cases they come by declaring the model, in the third case they come when I execute the command `logit_abst.getThresholds()`. I edited the third case in order to be clearer.

Comment: OK, what Spark version?

Comment: I'm working with Spark 2.2.0

Comment: To everyone: I updated the question with respect to the four answers here above. See the thread below with @desertnaut.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a messy situation indeed...

The **short** answer is:

1. `setThresholds` (plural) not clearing the threshold (singular) seems to be a bug
2. For multinomial classification (i.e. number of classes > 2), `setThresholds` **does not do** what you expect (and arguably you don't need it)
3. If all you need is having some "thresholds" in the "default" value of 0.5, you don't have a problem - simply don't use any relevant argument or `setThresholds` statement
4. If you really need to apply different decision thresholds to different classes in **multinomial** classification, you will have to do it manually, by post-processing the respective probabilities, i.e. the `probability` column in the transformed dataframe (it works OK though with `setThreshold(s)` for *binary* classification)

---

And now for the **long** answer...

Let's start with *binary* classification, adapting the toy data [from the docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression):

```python
spark.version
# u'2.2.0'

from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
bdf = sc.parallelize([
     Row(label=1.0, features=Vectors.dense(0.0, 5.0)),
     Row(label=0.0, features=Vectors.dense(1.0, 2.0)),

blor = LogisticRegression(threshold=0.7, thresholds=[0.3, 0.7])
     Row(label=1.0, features=Vectors.dense(2.0, 1.0)),
     Row(label=0.0, features=Vectors.dense(3.0, 3.0))]).toDF()
```

We don't need to set `thresholds` (plural) here - `threshold=0.7` is enough, but it will be useful when illustrating the differences with `setThreshold` below.

```python
blorModel = blor.fit(bdf) # works OK
blor.getThreshold()
# 0.7
blor.getThresholds()
# [0.3, 0.7]
blorModel.transform(bdf).show(truncate=False) # transform the training data
```

Here is the result:

```python
+---------+-----+------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+----------+
|features |label|rawPrediction                             |probability                             |prediction| 
+---------+-----+------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+----------+
|[0.0,5.0]|1.0  |[-1.138455151184087,1.138455151184087]    |[0.242604109995602,0.757395890004398]   |1.0       |
|[1.0,2.0]|0.0  |[-0.6056346859838877,0.6056346859838877]  |[0.35305562698104337,0.6469443730189567]|0.0       | 
|[2.0,1.0]|1.0  |[0.26586039040308496,-0.26586039040308496]|[0.5660763559614698,0.4339236440385302] |0.0       | 
|[3.0,3.0]|0.0  |[1.6453673835702176,-1.6453673835702176]  |[0.8382639556951765,0.16173604430482344]|0.0       | 
+---------+-----+------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+----------+
```

What is the meaning of `thresholds=[0.3, 0.7]`? The answer lies in the 2nd row, where the prediction is `0.0`, despite the fact that the the probability is higher for `1.0` (0.65): 0.65 is indeed higher that 0.35, but it is lower than the threshold we have set *for this class* (0.7), hence it is not classified as such.

Let's now try the *seemingly identical operation*, but with `setThreshold(s)` instead:

```python
blor2 = (LogisticRegression()
  .setThreshold(0.7)
  .setThresholds([0.3, 0.7]) ) # works OK

blorModel2 = blor2.fit(bdf)
[...]
IllegalArgumentException: u'requirement failed: Logistic Regression getThreshold found inconsistent values for threshold (0.5) and thresholds (equivalent to 0.7)'
```

Nice, eh?

`setThresholds` (plural) seems indeed to have cleared our value of threshold (0.7) set in the previous line, as claimed in the docs, but it seemingly did so only to restore it to its default value of 0.5...

Omitting `.setThreshold(0.7)` gives the first error you report yourself (not shown).

Inverting the order of the parameter settings resolves the issue (!!!) and, moreover, renders both `getThreshold` (singular) and `getThresholds` (plural) operational (in contrast with your case):

```python
blor2 = (LogisticRegression()
  .setThresholds([0.3, 0.7])
  .setThreshold(0.7) )

blorModel2 = blor2.fit(bdf) # works OK
blor2.getThreshold()
# 0.7
blor2.getThresholds()
# [0.30000000000000004, 0.7]
```

---

Let's move now to the *multinomial* case; we'll stick again to the example in the docs, with data from the [Spark Github repo](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/data/mllib/sample_multiclass_classification_data.txt) (they should also be available locally, in your `$SPARK_HOME/data/mllib/sample_multiclass_classification_data.txt`, but I am working on a Databricks notebook); it is a 3-class case, with labels in `{0.0, 1.0, 2.0}`.

```python
data_path ="/FileStore/tables/sample_multiclass_classification_data.txt"
mdf = spark.read.format("libsvm").load(data_path)
```

Similarly with the binary case above, where the elements of our `thresholds` (plural) sum up to 1, let's ask for a threshold of 0.8 for class 2:

```python
mlor = (LogisticRegression()
       .setFamily("multinomial")
       .setThresholds([0, 0.2, 0.8])
       .setThreshold(0.8) )
mlorModel= mlor.fit(mdf)  # works OK
mlor.getThreshold()
# 0.8
mlor.getThresholds()
# [0.19999999999999996, 0.8]
```

Looks fine, but let's ask for a *prediction* in the (training) dataset:

```python
mlorModel.transform(mdf).show(truncate=False)
```

I have singled out only one row - it should be the 2nd from the end of the full output:

```python
+-----+----------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+ 
|label|features                                            |rawPrediction                                            |probability                                                    |prediction| 
+-----+----------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
[...]
|0.0  |(4,[0,1,2,3],[0.111111,-0.333333,0.38983,0.166667]) |[36.67790353804905,-74.71196613173531,38.034062593686244]|[0.20486526556822454,8.619113376801409E-50,0.7951347344317755] |2.0       | 
[...]
+-----+----------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
```

Scrolling to the right, you'll see that despite the fact that the prediction for class `2.0` here is *below* the threshold we have set (0.8), the row is indeed predicted as `2.0` - in contrast with the binary case demonstrated above...

So, what to do? Simply **remove all the threshold-related statements**; you don't need them - even `setFamily` is unnecessary, as the algorithm will detect by itself that you have more than 2 classes. This will give identical results with the above:

```python
mlor = LogisticRegression() # works OK - no family, no threshold(s)
```

---

To **summarize**:

1. In both the binary & multinomial cases, what is actually returned by the algorithm is a vector of probabilities of length equal to the number of classes, with elements summing up to 1.
2. In the *binary case only*, Spark allows you to go one step further and not naively selecting the highest `probability` class as the `prediction`, but applying a user-defined threshold instead; this setting might be useful e.g. in cases with imbalanced data.
3. This `threshold(s)` setting has actually **no effect** in the *multinomial* case, where Spark will always return as `prediction` the class with the highest `probability`.

Despite the *mess* in the documentation (about which [I have argued elsewhere](https://www.nodalpoint.com/spark-classification/)) and the possibility of some bugs, let me say about (3) that this design choice is not unjustifiable; as it has been nicely argued [elsewhere](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/312119/classification-probability-threshold) (emphasis in the original):

> the statistical component of your exercise ends when you output a probability for each class of your new sample. Choosing a threshold beyond which you classify a new observation as 1 vs. 0 is not part of the *statistics* any more. It is part of the *decision* component.

Although the above argument was made for the binary case, it fully holds for the multinomial one, too...

Comment: Thank you very much for the exhaustive answer. It's unvaluable. I did some test and I was able to reconstruct the content of the columns `rawPrediction`, `probability` and `prediction` starting from the intercept and coefficients. I can now handle thresholds by hand, choosing suitable predictions.

Comment: As a further consideration, I agree that _this design choice is not unjustifiable_ as the thresholds setting _is part of the decision component_, but due to the incoherence with the documentation, and to the fact that the `setThresholds` command does exist, I still think this behavior is a bug. So I think it should be reported to Spark. They should either delete the `setThresholds` method or fix its behavior. What do you think about? Do you agree? Is it possible to report this in some way?

Comment: @VanniRovera you are very welcome (and now you have the necessary reputation to upvote the answer, too). I have in mind to report the issue myself, providing a link here; if you'd prefer to do it yourself, let me know.

Comment: If you want to report the issue yourself, this is fine with me. Just provide me the link in order to follow the thread and development of the discussion about. Thanks!

Comment: Didn't I already upvote the answer? Uhm... I see the orange up arrow enlighted

Comment: @desertnaut I believe in PySpark the 'threshold' methods are not available for RandomForest, and Gradient Boost Classifiers. Are you aware of any methods/techniques where I could tune the thresholds for a binary classification problem using RF,GBT classifiers?

Comment: @Rudr sorry, no